# how to use a tabbed application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitabbar

So I am using a tabbed application for the first time and need some help.

There are two views of the app:

- The 1st has a basic Gross Pay Calculator.
- The second has the option to select the taxes and make the changes.

My question is how do I take the information from view 1, the numbers, and have them be used in view 2, without having to reenter the numbers?

I am also using .xib and not storybords.

```
@synthesize totalpay, overtime;

//initWithNibName information is in here
////
//View did load and memory                  
////

//button to calculate the inputed hours and hourly pay
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender
{
    NSString *inVal = _hours.text;
    NSString *inVal2 = _pay.text;
    double hours = [inVal doubleValue];
    double pay = [inVal2 doubleValue];

    //check for overtime
    overtime = hours - 40;

    if( overtime > 0 )
    {
        totalpay = (( pay * 1.5) * overtime ) + (( hours - overtime ) * pay );
        _overtimeOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overtime Pay this week: $%.2f", totalpay];  
    }
    else
    {
        totalpay = hours * pay;
        _baseOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pay this week: $%.2f", totalpay];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**MODEL.**

You need to create a model.

This is the thing where you store the data and can use it from your controller to show it in any views.

Instead of storing every thing in local variables in the method, you can save them in a Model (it can be an Array, Dictionary, or a class). Then you can access these values.

> My question is how do i take the information from view 1, the numbers,
>   and have them be used in view 2, without having to reenter the
>   numbers.

If you have one controller for *Tabs* then you can easily use the properties for both the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton class is what you're looking for. It's something like a class with static properties which you initialize only once and then you can use it for sharing data between other objects (e.g. views). All you have to do is to include its header file.

Here's a good example how to make a singleton class in ObjC: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/